# How to get accurate geolocation in Firefox on Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: firefox, 21.10, google, geolocation

With Firefox 97.0 on Ubuntu 21.10, when I try to let a website access my location, e.g. so that it can center a map around where I currently am, it doesn't work. And yes, I've allowed the website to access location, etc.

[image]

(Example: [www.openstreetmap.org](http://www.openstreetmap.org) after clicking the current location button)

I did some research and found out that the Google location service (which is set as default in Firefox) does not work on some Linux distributions, and that instead it's possible to switch to Mozilla's own location service (see this [ArchWiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/firefox#Geolocation_does_not_work), for example). They blame Google for this issue, they seem to be blocking some Linux distributions (why? how?).

So after I changed `geo.provider.network.url` to `https://location.services.mozilla.com/v1/geolocate?key=%MOZILLA_API_KEY%` in `about:config` as instructed, the location service indeed started to work, however it consistently locates me ~200km north-west of my actual location and is thus utterly useless.

Usually I would be content using a Mozilla service over a Google service - but when that means the quality is so much worse, I reconsider. And from what I can see from [this Mozilla blog post](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/retiring-mozilla-stumbler/75206), they are not even collecting new location info anymore, because their submission client has been discontinued in 2021. Which explains the bad data quality, I suppose.

Does anyone know what I have to do to get Google location service on my Ubuntu Firefox? Maybe there is a way to circumvent Google's block?

And should the non-working geo-location (with default settings) be considered a bug in Ubuntu's Firefox package?

Comment: I have never changed this setting and it was set to mozillas service (on windows). Just off by ~2km... But also I just remembered this: https://xkcd.com/713/

Comment: Obtaining an accurate set of coordinates on a device that doesn’t have a GPS radio is going to be a challenge. That said, have you tried changing the UserAgent string in the browser to mimic a Windows or MacOS string?

Comment: Not sure whether or not I tried that - but somehow the problem fixed itself to some degree. The center of the location indicated is now at the center of my city (which is good enough for me). The "circle of uncertainty" or whatever this is called is still quite large though, ~30km radius. Still using the Mozilla service.

Answer (score 0):

IP-based geolocation is based upon locations reported by the ISP that issued you that particular IP address.

If your ISP reports the location of your current block of IP addresses to be 200km northwest of you, perhaps that's their home office. Or perhaps the administrative office of a subsidiary. Or some other (current or past) facility of theirs.

Contact your ISP to report the issue and ask them to correct the location of your IP address. It's doubtful they will bother to do so unless you are an especially lucrative customer. But maybe they will.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that. But somehow Google gets super-accurate down to a few meters results, even with this being a Desktop computer, connected to a LAN cable. Probably because my Android phone is in the same network, reporting its accurately determined position, and then Google pinpoints all other devices with that public IP address at the same location. Something like that... Anyway, my disappointment was actually mostly that I as a Ubuntu + Firefox user can't use that accurate Google service.

Comment: Complain to Google: "*[T]hey seem to be blocking some Linux distributions*" suggests that they could unblock if they wanted to.